# Exoplayer within AndroidView not switching video when setting a new MediaItem on the fly

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So I got declared an exoplayer2 inside a composable function like this:

```
    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(3f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(RoundedSizeStatic.Medium))
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(RoundedSizeStatic.Medium),
                    spotColor = Color.White,
                    ambientColor = Color.White
                )
            ,
            factory = {
                PlayerView(viewModel.context).apply {
                    player = largeVideoPlayerHandler.videoPlayer
                    useController = false
                    resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL

                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    ) {
        onDispose {
            largeVideoPlayerHandler.videoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
```

and the video exoplayer is initiated like this:

```
fun GetCameraPlayer(url: String): ExoPlayer {
    var rendersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(context).forceEnableMediaCodecAsynchronousQueueing() //prevent buffering memory leaks


    var newExoPlayer: ExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).setRenderersFactory(rendersFactory).build().apply {
        setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
        repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
        playWhenReady = true

        prepare()

    }

    return newExoPlayer
```

the initial video is being displayed fine, but whenever I try to change and prepare the next MediaItem for this Exoplayer it won't change. Code:

```
fun SwitchLargeVideoDisplay(url: String) {

    largeVideoDisplay.videoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
    largeVideoDisplay.videoPlayer.prepare()
}
```

videoPlayer is the Exoplayer which was returned.

The funny thing is that whenever I execute this `SwitchLargeVideoDisplay`in the same composable function it does work. But executing this code outside of this composable function with the correct refrence to the exoPlayer, the exoplayer won't change its video/mediaItem

somebody knows a solution for this problem?